# Integer polynomial inducing a permutation of order $p$ on $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ for infinitely many $p$

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers

Let $Q\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ be a non-linear polynomial. Can there exist infinitely many primes $p$ such that $Q(\mathrm{mod}\:p)$ induces a permutation $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ of order $p$?

Comment: For each $x$, the quantity $Q(x)-x-1$ would be divisible by infinitely many primes, therefore it has to be zero.

Comment: @GjergjiZaimi sorry, that was stupid on my part. I edited.

Comment: You can also look up permutation polynomials, in particular the structure theorem (aka Schur conjecture but it's no longer a conjecture) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_polynomial

Comment: Let $k>0$ be an odd integer. By the Dirichlet Theorem, there are infinitely many primes $p$ such that $p\equiv 2\pmod k$. Clearly we have gcd$(k,p-1)=1$. Then the polynomial 
$$Q(x)=x^k\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$$
is a permutation polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.